# Does anyone know if AVSpeechUtterance supports SSML?

Tags: ios, ssml, avspeechutterance

Was wondering if anyone knew if AVSpeechUtterance supports SSML?

Comment: hey, did you find anything on this?

Comment: yea they don't support it but that was a year ago when i checked

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation, it seems they do not.

Comment: Can you include the relevant documentation, if you still have a reference?

Comment: There's no mention of SSML https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechutterance